# Differences between SIunits and siunitx packages

Tags: siunitx

I was reviewing [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex), and noticed that the `siunitx` package was recommended. I have been using `\usepackage[mediumspace,mediumqspace,squaren,binary]{SIunits}`.

So, what are the differences between these two packages? Has the `SIUnits` been deprecated?  Are there anything to watch out for when switching from `SIUnits` to `siunitx`?

Ideally I would like to use a package that takes care of non-SI units as well, such as miles, lbs, Fahrenheit temperature, etc.

Comment: Here is a useful summary of [what packages should be used to typeset units](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-package-should-i-use-to-typeset-units).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To add to Seamus's answer, `siunitx` combines the functionality of `SIstyle` and `SIunits`, hence having a new name. As a result, both `SIstyle` and `SIunits` now have 'bug-fix only' status.

`siunitx` can operate in two ways. The recommended way is to require that units are used within the arguments to macros `\SI` and `\si`:

```
\SI{10}{\metre}
\si{\kilogram\metre\per\second} % Note no `\usk' here
```

It is possible to load the package such that 'free-standing' units are defined (`\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}`), but this can lead to some macro-naming awkwardness and also makes some functions less reliable.

The package defines a number of units 'out of the box', but these are all SI units. For the next release (v2.3), I will be adding abbreviated units to the set that are defined automatically (currently these are a load-time option):

```
\SI{13.4}{\kg\per\V}
```

Binary units are available as a load-time option. (I may make these automatic for v2.3: I have not yet decided.) New units can be defined in the preamble

```
\DeclareSIUnit\lb{lb}
...
\SI{100}{\lb}
```

or you can include units without any definition

```
\SI{60}{mph}
\SI{100}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree F}
\si{psi}
```

Settings in `siunitx` are controlled by the `\sisetup` macro. For the spacing you load with `SIunits`, the options needed are

```
\sisetup{number-unit-product = \:, inter-unit-product = \:}
```

Comment: OK, looks like I need to transition to siunitx. What does the Note no '\usk' here comment referring to?

Comment: @Peter: It is possible to define a relatively short 'translation' layer - I can add that to the answer if you like. The `\usk` macro is required in `SIunits` where there is a product of units, but `siunitx` does not require such a macro.

Comment: Anything that helps with the transition would be helpful as long as it is not too much work...

Comment: @Peter: Looking back through my notes, I remember now that this is not so straight-forward. Perhaps you might post a follow-up question, showing how _you_ use `SIunits`, and I can answer the more limited 'how are these particular things done' question.

Answer (score 12):

`siunitx` is written by Joseph Wright who did, for a time, maintain `SIunits`.  `siunitx` replaces `SIunits` and another package called `SIstyle`. It is a complete reimplementation of the basic idea.

It can handle non-SI units with ease. The [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) has the details of how to define new units.

Comment: Indeed, I still am (in a formal sense) the maintainer of `SIunits`, which I took over around the time `siunitx` development started.

Comment: @Joseph I thought so: I read your recent TUGboat article about it...