# Migrating from SIunits to siunitx: are there any obvious pitfall?

Tags: siunitx, siunits

I understood the differences that were mentioned at the following link.
[Differences between SIunits and siunitx packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21936/differences-between-siunits-and-siunitx-packages)

I am using TexStudio and MikTeX (perhaps the most recent version, considering that I downloaded the whole bundle yesterday) for typesetting my document. After changing all `\unit` to `\SI` I am still getting errors like `line 0 Undefined control sequence`.

How should I get around this problem?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a small demo of your `SIunits` input.

Comment: With no concrete demo, this is 'too localized', I'm afraid