# Align table by dot - Not with siunitx

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, dcolumn

I'm trying to align numbers in a table by the dots.
I know of one method using the `siunitx` package. But I can't load the package.
siunitx error:

```
"incompatible-package"! Package 'SIunits' incompatible. \__siunitx_load_check:n
```

Probably a conflict to the SIunit package which I'm using.

But I found another way to make the aligning but the table doesn't fit the numbers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,icelandic]{report}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1} }
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|rcld{1}|}
    \hline
      $O_{3}(g) + 2H^{+} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $O_{2}(g) + H_{2}O$ & 2.07     \\
    $H_{2}O_{2} + 2H^{+} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 H_{2}O$          & 1.776    \\
                    $Au^{+}+e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Au$                & 1.68     \\
                $Cl_{2}(g)+2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 Cl^{-}$          & 1.3583   \\
      $O_{2}(g) + 4H^{+} + 4e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 H_{2}O$          & 1.229    \\
    $H_{2}O_{2} + 2e^{-} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 OH^{-}$          & 0.88     \\
                  $ Ag^{+}+e^{-} $ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Ag$                & 0.7996   \\
           $ O_{2}+2H_{2}O+4e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $4 OH^{-}$          & 0.401    \\ \hline
                 $ 2H^{+}+2e^{-} $ & $\rightleftharpoons$ &                     & 0.000... \\ \hline
                  $Fe^{3+}+3e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Fe$                & -0.036   \\ \hline

\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have told `dcolumn` that you only have one decimal place in the numbers so it only leaves room for one digit after the `.` Also please always post complete documents not fragments with bits removed. The `2.4` leaves enough room for a minus sign and a digit to the left of the . and 4 digits after.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,icelandic]{report}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1} }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|rcld{2.4}|}
    \hline
      $O_{3}(g) + 2H^{+} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $O_{2}(g) + H_{2}O$ & 2.07     \\
    $H_{2}O_{2} + 2H^{+} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 H_{2}O$          & 1.776    \\
                    $Au^{+}+e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Au$                & 1.68     \\
                $Cl_{2}(g)+2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 Cl^{-}$          & 1.3583   \\
      $O_{2}(g) + 4H^{+} + 4e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 H_{2}O$          & 1.229    \\
    $H_{2}O_{2} + 2e^{-} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 OH^{-}$          & 0.88     \\
                  $ Ag^{+}+e^{-} $ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Ag$                & 0.7996   \\
           $ O_{2}+2H_{2}O+4e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $4 OH^{-}$          & 0.401    \\ \hline
                 $ 2H^{+}+2e^{-} $ & $\rightleftharpoons$ &                     & 0.000\\ \hline
                  $Fe^{3+}+3e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Fe$                & -0.036   \\ \hline

\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this David. Just used 2.6 and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your `...` in the second-to-last row in your table. I was able to use the `siunitx` package by replacing `...` with `\dots`.

Also, have a look at the `mhchem` package. I've replaced your first equation using the `\ce{}` command provided by `mhchem`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|rclS|}
    \hline
      \ce{O3_{(g)} + 2H+ + 2e-} & \ce{<=>} & \ce{O2_{(g)} + H2O} & 2.07     \\
    $H_{2}O_{2} + 2H^{+} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 H_{2}O$          & 1.776    \\
                    $Au^{+}+e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Au$                & 1.68     \\
                $Cl_{2}(g)+2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 Cl^{-}$          & 1.3583   \\
      $O_{2}(g) + 4H^{+} + 4e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 H_{2}O$          & 1.229    \\
    $H_{2}O_{2} + 2e^{-} + 2e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $2 OH^{-}$          & 0.88     \\
                  $ Ag^{+}+e^{-} $ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Ag$                & 0.7996   \\
           $ O_{2}+2H_{2}O+4e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $4 OH^{-}$          & 0.401    \\ \hline
                 $ 2H^{+}+2e^{-} $ & $\rightleftharpoons$ &                     & 0.000\dots \\ \hline
                  $Fe^{3+}+3e^{-}$ & $\rightleftharpoons$ & $Fe$                & -0.036   \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But for some reason I can't load the siunitx package due to conflict to the SIunit package. I'm using commands that siunitx doesn't support elsewhere in my thesis. Like \degree \micro e.t.c. - But I also want to thank you for introducing me to the chem package.

Comment: @bjartmar You're welcome. You might consider taking another look at the `siunitx` documentation. I'm certain it has the equivalent of the commands you mention, but the implementation might be slightly different. Here is a good place to start 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21943/24974

Comment: Thanks again. I will definitely take a look at this later. I'm just about to finish this thesis. It would take me to long to figure everything out. :)