# SIunits package - separating value and unit

Tags: spacing, units, siunits

Can the space between the value and the unit be added automatically, when units are written using the `SIunits` package?

The package gives the following two options to add units:

```
$500\kelvin$
$\unit{500}{\kelvin}$
```

[image]

Only the latter adds seperation between value and unit. Adding the `\unit{...}{...}` parameter is too cumbersome and doesn't give any ease of use compared to the manual `\;\mathrm{...}` method.

Using the former notation to avoid this, the space can be added manually with `\;` of course, `500\;\kelvin`, but I am now looking for the possibility of never having to add anything but the unit.

I have [looked into](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21936/differences-between-siunits-and-siunitx-packages) the `siunitx` package as well, which only replaces the `\unit{...}{...}` with `\SI{...}{...}` (and apparently makes it mandatory!). This therefore gives no help.

Is it possible to automatically/generally add a `\;` before every single unit (and unit group) in the document?

Comment: The package information says “Note that the pack­age is now su­per­seded by siu­nitx; siu­nits has main­te­nance-only sup­port, now.” So that’s your answer: use siunitx, not SIunits.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Indeed: I'm at least formally in charge of `SIunits`. The statement means that there will be no features _added_, but here we are talking about usage of _existing_ abilities (thought I'd still go with `siunitx`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One could achieve this in `SIunits` by patching an appropriate internal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\SI@fstyle{\;}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$500\;\mathrm{K}$

$500\kelvin$

\end{document}
```

You can also do this in `siunitx` by activating 'free standing' units and 'pre-spacing'

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{free-standing-units, space-before-unit, number-unit-product = \;}
\begin{document}

$500\;\mathrm{K}$

$500\kelvin$

\end{document}
```

(Using `\qty` is recommended as there are outcomes that require a more structured mark-up, but one design aim has always been to support a range of input forms.)

---

For these approaches to work you have to have the unit as a single command: chaining things together such as `\volt\per\kelvin` won't work as there is no way to 'know' what marks the end of the unit. For `siunitx` we can declare a new unit which will then only add a space at the start

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{free-standing-units, space-before-unit, number-unit-product = \;}
\DeclareSIUnit{\voltperkelvin}{\volt\per\kelvin}
\begin{document}

$500\;\mathrm{V}\,\mathrm{K}^{-1}$

$500\voltperkelvin$

\end{document}
```

(The need to define units 'up front' for 'pre-spacing' to work is one reason the `siunitx` documentation is primarily focussed on logic mark up.)

This is much harder to achieve with `SIunits` as the unit commands are not context-sensitive. One might add appropriate switching but this becomes a significant change in the way the code works: probably crosses into 'development' (which as the `SIunits` documentation says is now done in `siunitx`.)

Answer (score 3):

You can control the spacing with `number-unit-product`, either as package option, or with `\sisetup` or locally only within `\SI[number-unit-product=...]{500}{\kelvin}`, but you should think about this whether this is **really** needed

(Of course, `\quad` is exaggerated!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[number-unit-product=\quad]{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\SI{500}{\kelvin}
% Local change
\SI[number-unit-product=\,\,]{1000}{\meter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Steeven: I understood that but I don't recommend it ;-) I had a similar approach in all of my worksheets etc. for my students and switched (with some help of `\sed` etc. to `\SI` usage.