# No newline before scientific units without using "~"

Tags: line-breaking, units

Is it possible to define a list of units (like ml, °C, nmol, eq., etc.) and forbid latex to insert a newline before those?

I know it is possible to use a ~ between number an unit, but the above described method would be much more convenient for me.

Thanks for helping me!

edit:
thanks for all the comments and answers, but maybe i should explain my reason to look for something like that: I have a very large Document (not yet written in latex) and try to format it using latex. Therefore it would be quite time consuming to edit every value and unit to fit the `siunitx` syntax. Same problem with the answer from [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252251).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-package-should-i-use-to-typeset-units

Comment: See Josephs link, just wanted to mention that in most cases `~` would be the wrong spacing to use. It should be smaller.

Comment: @JosephWright: thanks for the link, even though it does not directly answer my question (see edit), it provides some interesting information on your package, that seems to be very useful for scientific documents. I will certainly use it in the future.

Comment: @daleif: are you sure? I cannot see any difference when exchanging the ~ with a normal "space". What would you recommend instead?

Comment: @ail246 `\,` is the usual recommendation: a thin space.

Comment: I've reopened based on the edit: feel free to ping me and request closing again if this seems wrong.

Comment: @JosephWright oh, i got the comment wrong. I thought he meant that the `~` would be bigger than a usual text-space... thanks for the advice to both of you

Comment: Might me time consuming, but still the right to to do

Comment: @daleif well it seems to be the only possibility..

Answer (score 2):

If you want minimal mark-up, you can do it using `siunitx` using either

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{free-standing-units, space-before-unit, use-xspace}
\begin{document}

10\metre or even 10\m (a bit risky)

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{free-standing-units, unit-optional-argument}
\begin{document}

\metre[10] or even \m[10] (a bit risky)

\end{document}
```

or you could use the older `unitsdef` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unitsdef}
\begin{document}

10\meter or \meter[10].

\end{document}
```

(Notice that the `siunitx` syntax for 'free-standing' units is in-part based on `unitsdef`.) As noted in comments and in [What package should I use to typeset units?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-package-should-i-use-to-typeset-units), the 'preferred' syntax in `siunitx` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI{10}{\metre} or even \SI{10}{\m}.

\end{document}
```

as this provides more logical mark-up but also more programmatic control of outcomes. In any of the `siunitx` cases, the space is adjustable *via* a key and will not break unless the appropriate setting is altered.

Comment: thanks for summarizing the possibilities in `SIunitx`. I really appreciate how much effort you make to help a noob like me. I think I'm going to write a small perl programm using regular expressions to get all the units into the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If one chooses to not use the `siunitx` package which was designed to handle units, one could define `\myunit{}` that accomplishes the goal of avoiding such breaks before the unit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\myunit#1{\unskip\,\textrm{#1}}
\begin{document}
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
8 \myunit{ml}\ or $\pi \myunit{$^\circ$C}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\DeclareSIUnit{\Fahrenheit}{\degree\,F}
\DeclareSIUnit{\drachm}{dr\,av}
\DeclareSIUnit{\oz}{oz\,av}
\DeclareSIUnit{\yard}{yd}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}

Here is a list of some typical non SI units:
\begin{itemize*}[itemjoin=\hskip0.8em, afterlabel=\hskip0.25em, before=\quad]
  \item \si{\celsius}
  \item \si{\Fahrenheit}
  \item \si{\decibel}
  \item \si{\drachm}
  \item \si{\drachm\per\yard\squared}
\end{itemize*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's drav/drachm? Sorry, I know this isn't really on topic, I'm just really curious! I wikipedia'd drachm and found something that made sense, but it didn't mention drav.

Comment: Celsius is an SI unit :-)

Comment: Is it? I thought it was the Kelvin

Comment: @Au101: It is 1/16 n ounce, or 1/256 pound in the *avoirdupois* imperial system, about `1.772 g`. Not to be confused with the `apothecaries` drachm, 1/96 pound, subdivided in `3 scruples`.

Comment: I think Celsius is an SI derived unit http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html. Kelvin is the *bona fide* SI unit

Comment: @Au101 Both are _bona fide_ SI units, derived units are quite allowed: http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/.

Comment: @JosephWright No doubt. Sorry, I didn't mean it quite like that. But Kelvin is the base unit, it's the ... it's the 24 carat SI unit, it's the pure SI unit, not based on any other SI unit, the fundamental, the element, you know what I mean