# Superscript in a sentence

Tags: superscripts

How to start a sentence after using the superscript in latex

for eg. Ground plane is constructed with dimensions of 25\times10.5 mm^2 and the thickness of \ac{PEC} is 0.035 mm over the substrate. A triangular slot of height 4 mm is cut from the ground plane. Two sectors of radii 4 mm is also subtracted from the ground plane. This slotting is done in order to achieve the more optimized s-parameter value.

it is not coming in the way it is supposed to come.

Comment: Welcome to SX. Could you provide a minimal working example of your code so that we can see what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Based on what you post I suspect that you are forgetting the math delimiters. But please provide a MWE

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. It is also helpful to explain in detail what your desired output is.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX SE. P.S., note that units should not be typeset in the same way as variables. [See this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-package-should-i-use-to-typeset-units)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want your output to be:

[image]

You must enter "math mode" by enclosing your math content with `$..$`. Or, `\(..\)` will have the same effect. There are several ways to code the superscript for your units. The code

`dimensions of $25\times10.5$\,mm\textsuperscript{2} and`

will provide the output above. I recommend, however, that you consider the package `siunitx` for proper formatting of units. [Information can be found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-package-should-i-use-to-typeset-units).

Comment: With this setup, a line break is possible between `$25\times10.5$` and `mm\textsuperscript{2}` -- something that's frowned on, typographically speaking. Can you think of a way to prohibit such inopportune line breaks?

Comment: It's more common to use `\,` (thinspace) rather than a full interword space (`~`) to join the number part and the associated units.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Mico. I edited my response.

Answer (score 2):

i would use `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
correct: \SI{15 x 10.5}{mm}

your wish: \SI[product-units=single]{15 x 10.5}{mm\tothe2}
or \SI[product-units=single]{15 x 10.5}{mm^2}

\end{document}
```

[image]