# How do I un-italicize units when writing equations? For example, I need to un-italicize m/s, m, and Hz

Tags: equations

Here's and example of what I have which italicizes everything:

```
\begin{equation} 
\lambda = c/f = (3x10^8~m/s)/2x10^8~Hz = 1.5~m
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. You could take a look at the features of the `siunitx` package, which is for formatting numbers with and without units, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-package-should-i-use-to-typeset-units/2254#2254

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hello, thank you so much! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
\newcommand{\amt}[2]{\ensuremath{#1\,\mathrm{#2}}}
```

which is used like `\amt{9.80}{m/s^2}` and can be used in either text or math mode.

You can also take a look at the `siunitx` package.